# Mouseover overlay for images using Views Photo Grid

Tags: theming

Trying to add a hover overlay for node title and a couple of other fields for images using  the [views photos grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_photo_grid) module.

The fields to be used in the overlay need be excluded from the display as the module only uses one image field, however I am not managing to add the excluded fields.

If I the preprocess to template.php

```
`function THEME_preprocess_views_photo_grid_style(&$vars) { $vars['raw_result'] = $vars['view']->style_plugin->rendered_fields;}`
```

I can print the titles using

```
`foreach ($raw_result as $row) {print $row['title']; }`
```

which prints the titles on the page outside the container as a row, but I can only add the last title to the overlay. 
Need to be able combine each title to each image that is shown using

```
`foreach ($items as $key => $item):
```

`print $item;`
`endforeach;`

Comment: You can accomplish this with CSS and jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

As the arrays line up, added an index and combined the arrays

```
$index = 0; foreach ($items as $key => $item):
print $raw_result[$index]['title']; $index++
print $item;
```

Works